# Turn on Gravity on current object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a simple game - when I click on the screen a cube should start using gravity (I have unchecked the "Use Gravity" setting for that cube). However, I do not know how to reference it. I found that I could write `.useGravity = true;` but I have no idea what to put before the dot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because for "I don't know what to type before the dot" questions, a very basic tutorial (widely available) is more suitable than a QA.

Answer (score 3):

Gravity comes from the RigidBody. So use something like this in the code.

```
GetComponent<RigidBody>.useGravity=true;
```

This of course assumes your script is acting on the same object. If you need to get another object, well, that's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

You can give him a special name like "CubePlayer" and after in your code reference him as:

```
GameObject.Find("CubePlayer").use....
```

Other way is to assign a var to it from Inspector, in JavaScript it is like this:

```
public var MyCube : GameObject;   
...
MyCube.use.....
```

It is possible in C to do this too.

Comment: The OP is after the `RigidBody` _component_ so `GameObject.Find` is not suitable (due to the latter searching for `GameObject`s)

Comment: Please avoid "thank you notes" in your posts and stick with language requested in the question.